# C# MVC RouteConfig.cs

Tags: c#, asp.net, model-view-controller

Can I use session variable to filter the route.

```
 public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
 {               
        // can I use here session variable to filter the route

        routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");

        routes.MapRoute(
            name: "Default",
            url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
            defaults: new { controller = "Login", action = "Login", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
        );
    }
```

Comment: Please include a question.

Comment: If possible, use routing attributes rather than the RouteConfig file.  As far as using session variables, do you mean like authorization tags?  `[AllowAnonmous]`, that kind of thing?

Comment: Give more information, please.

Comment: What did you mean by filter the route ? What is the rule? Maybe you need Authentication and Authorization :)

Answer (score 2):

Yes, it's possible to use session variables to select (or even ignore) a specific route (I assume that's what you mean).  You can do this using [Route Constraints](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/mvc/overview/older-versions-1/controllers-and-routing/creating-a-custom-route-constraint-cs)

```
public class SessionConstraint : IRouteConstraint
{
    public bool Match
        (
            HttpContextBase httpContext, 
            Route route, 
            string parameterName, 
            RouteValueDictionary values, 
            RouteDirection routeDirection
        )
    {
        return Session["Foo"]; // value in session is true/false
                               // or use some other expression that is true/false
    }
}
```

You would then use this like so:

```
routes.MapRoute(
    name: "Default",
    url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
    defaults: new { controller = "Login", action = "Login", id = UrlParameter.Optional },
    new {sessionValue=new SessionConstraint()}
);
```

The idea here is that we can now use this as a constraint on whether the condition is a match or not.

One note of caution though.  If you're thinking about using this for security purposes, don't.  Session values are easily spoofed because session cookies are not encrypted.